# Inline-block not working because of white-space: nowrap;

Tags: html, text, overflow, css

I´m currently trying to make an inline article for a school project. 
The text is overflowing and I´m not sure why, but I have an idea. 
When I remove white-space: nowrap; - the text doing what it´s suppose to, fill the pink box, but then the inline doesnt work any more.

Any ideas? I have attached a codepen.

http://codepen.io/torarne_n/pen/PwQBmx

```
.slider {
width: 1225px;
height: 600px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: #ccc;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.slides {
height:500px;
width:1225px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: aqua;
}

.intro-image {
height: auto;
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
background-color: pink;
}

.intro-text {
height: auto;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the inner elements are inherriting the `nowrap`.  Simply set it back to normal on the inner elements:

```
.intro-text {
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    white-space: normal;
}
```